# How to hard delete objects older than n-days in LakeFS?

Tags: object-storage, lakefs

How to find and hard delete objects older than n-days in LakeFS? Later it'll be a scheduled job.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do that you should use the [Garbage Collection](https://docs.lakefs.io/reference/garbage-collection.html) (GC) feature in lakeFS.

**Note:** This feature cleans objects from the storage only after they are deleted from your branches in lakeFS.

You will need to:

1. Define GC rules to set your desired retention period.

   From the lakeFS UI, go to the repository you would like to hard delete objects from -> Settings -> Retention, and define the GC rule for each branch under the repository. For example -

   ```
   {
       "default_retention_days": 21,
       "branches": [
           {"branch_id": "main", "retention_days": 28},
           {"branch_id": "dev", "retention_days": 7}
       ]
   }
   ```
2. Run the GC Spark job that does the actual cleanup, with -

   ```
   spark-submit --class io.treeverse.clients.GarbageCollector \
     -c spark.hadoop.lakefs.api.url=https://lakefs.example.com:8000/api/v1  \
     -c spark.hadoop.lakefs.api.access_key=<LAKEFS_ACCESS_KEY> \
     -c spark.hadoop.lakefs.api.secret_key=<LAKEFS_SECRET_KEY> \
     -c spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.access.key=<S3_ACCESS_KEY> \
     -c spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.secret.key=<S3_SECRET_KEY> \
     --packages io.lakefs:lakefs-spark-client-301_2.12:0.5.0 \
     example-repo us-east-1
   ```

Comment: ty, but how actually find and delete this ogjects?

Comment: You can use the [Python API client](https://docs.lakefs.io/integrations/python.html) lakeFS provides to list objects, filter them by mtime, and delete them. If this does not support the scale of your environment, you can use the [Metadata client](https://github.com/treeverse/lakeFS/tree/master/clients/spark) to achieve the same goal from Spark.

Comment: Sounds good ty!